# How to render the actual value of the scroll percentage?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, animation, scroll

I have this piece of code

```
import React from 'react'

const App = () => {  

function getScrollPercent() {
  var h = document.documentElement, 
    b = document.body,
    st = 'scrollTop',
    sh = 'scrollHeight';

  var scrollPercent = Math.round((h[st]||b[st]) / ((h[sh]||b[sh]) - h.clientHeight) * 100);
  //get the percentage of scroll

  return (isNaN(scrollPercent) ? '' : scrollPercent)
}

return (
  <p>{`${getScrollPercent()}%`}</p>
)
```

the problem is when I scroll the scrollPercent doesn't refresh in real time but only when the scroll stop, so scrollPercent can pass from 0% to 100% and not display all the numbers between 0 and 100, so the question is how can I modify my piece of code to display the actual value of scrollPercent even when I scroll

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use a `useEffect` to add an event listener that will listen for the scroll event. Then, you can register a function that will re-calculate the scroll position when the user scrolls up or down the page.

```js
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";

function getScrollPercent() {
  var h = document.documentElement,
    b = document.body,
    st = "scrollTop",
    sh = "scrollHeight";

  var scrollPercent = Math.round(
    ((h[st] || b[st]) / ((h[sh] || b[sh]) - h.clientHeight)) * 100
  );
  //get the percentage of scroll

  return isNaN(scrollPercent) ? "" : scrollPercent;
}

const App = () => {
  // this represents the current calculated scroll percentage
  // maybe initialize this to something other than empty string
  const [scrollPercentage, setScrollPercentage] = useState("");

  useEffect(() => {
    function handleScroll() {
      const newScrollPercentage = getScrollPercent();

      // calculate and set the new scroll percentage
      setScrollPercentage(newScrollPercentage);
    }

    window.addEventListener("scroll", handleScroll, true);

    // clean up event listener when component unmounts
    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener('scroll', handleScroll, true);
    }
  }, []);

  // this contains extra styling to demo, so that you can see the 
  // scroll value change when scrolling, probably remove these style props
  return (
    <div style={{ height: "3000px" }}>
      <p style={{ position: "fixed" }}>{`${scrollPercentage}%`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Codesandbox Link to example: [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/hungry-mcclintock-3bz3l?file=/src/App.js:633-777)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use window.addEventListener to reach what you want.

```
import React from "react";

const App = () => {
  const [scroll, setScroll] = React.useState("");

  function getScrollPercent() {
    var h = document.documentElement,
      b = document.body,
      st = "scrollTop",
      sh = "scrollHeight";

    var scrollPercent = Math.round(
      ((h[st] || b[st]) / ((h[sh] || b[sh]) - h.clientHeight)) * 100
    );

    setScroll(isNaN(scrollPercent) ? "" : scrollPercent);
  }

  React.useEffect(() => {
    window.addEventListener("scroll", getScrollPercent);

    return () => {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", getScrollPercent);
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ height: "1000px" }}>
      <p style={{ position: "fixed" }}>{`${scroll}%`}</p>
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Codesanbox Link: https://codesandbox.io/s/unruffled-field-3l3z8?file=/src/App.js:0-664

Comment: This will cause additional overhead because `getScrollPercent` will be regenerated on every render. Also, the imports `useState` and `useEffect` are missing.

Comment: It's not necessary import useState and useEffect because it's been called with React.
And about the overhead I'm not sure it's true.